# Boost.Asio contrived example inexplicably blocking

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I've used Boost.Asio extensively, but I've came across a problem with a unit test that I don't understand.  I've reduced the problem down to a very contrived example:

```
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE My_Module
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp>

using namespace std::string_literals;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace BA = boost::asio;
namespace BAI = BA::ip;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test)
{
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;

    BA::io_service servicer;
    auto io_work = std::make_unique<BA::io_service::work>(servicer);

    auto thread = std::thread{[&]() {
        servicer.run();
    }};

    auto received_response = false;

    auto server_buf = std::array<std::uint8_t, 4096>{};
    auto server_sock = BAI::tcp::socket{servicer};
    auto acceptor = BAI::tcp::acceptor{servicer,
                                       BAI::tcp::endpoint{BAI::tcp::v4(), 20123}};
    acceptor.async_accept(server_sock, [&](auto&& ec) {
        if (ec) {
            BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(ec.message());
        }
        BOOST_REQUIRE(!ec);

        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Accepted connection from " << server_sock.remote_endpoint() <<
                           ", reading...");

        BA::async_read(server_sock,
                       BA::buffer(server_buf),
                       [&](auto&& ec, auto&& bytes_read){
            std::unique_lock<decltype(m)> ul(m);
            received_response = true;

            if (ec) {
                BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(ec.message());
            }
            BOOST_REQUIRE(!ec);

            const auto str = std::string{server_buf.begin(),
                                         server_buf.begin() + bytes_read};
            BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Read: " << str);

            ul.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
        });
    });

    const auto send_str = "hello"s;
    auto client_sock = BAI::tcp::socket{servicer, BAI::tcp::v4()};
    client_sock.async_connect(BAI::tcp::endpoint{BAI::tcp::v4(), 20123},
                              [&](auto&& ec) {
        if (ec) {
            BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(ec.message());
        }
        BOOST_REQUIRE(!ec);

        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Connected...");
        BA::async_write(client_sock,
                        BA::buffer(send_str),
                        [&](auto&& ec, auto&& bytes_written) {
            if (ec) {
                BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE(ec.message());
            }
            BOOST_REQUIRE(!ec);

            BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Written " << bytes_written << " bytes");
        });
    });

    std::unique_lock<decltype(m)> ul(m);
    cv.wait_for(ul, 2s, [&](){ return received_response; });
    BOOST_CHECK(received_response);

    io_work.reset();
    servicer.stop();
    if (thread.joinable()) {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

which I compile with:

```
g++ -std=c++17 source.cc -l boost_unit_test_framework -pthread -l boost_system -ggdb
```

The output is:

```
Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:51688, reading...
Connected...
Written 5 bytes
```

And then it times out.

Running through the debugger shows that the `async_read` handler is never called.  Pausing execution during the phase where it doesn't seem to be doing anything, shows that the main thread is waiting on the `condition_variable` (`cv`) and the `io_service` thread is on an `epoll_wait`.

I seem to be deadlocking but can't see how.

Comment: first guess: client not issuing a shutdown so the read is not completing because it's trying to read more data (4096) than was sent (send_string.size()).

Comment: @RichardHodges but what if I need a response, surely issuing a shutdown will result in the connection being closed before I receive one?  I _assumed_ that I because the sender buffer is under the OS's MTU the server socket would fire the read handler after a received packet  - am I assuming too much?

Comment: @RichardHodges I should add that I did try adding a `client_sock.shutdown(..)` to the bottom of the write handler, but it just triggered an 'End of stream' error in the read handler.  Setting the read buffer to be 5 bytes made the system work, so you're definitely right in principle, but obviously I can't know the send size in advance.

Comment: Note, I had to add some missing includes and defines and then your sample code still doesn't compile due to a missing variable definitions `m` and `cv`. I've edited your question to make it compile, including adding compile instructions for Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the function is defined to work, it waits for exactly the number of bytes that the buffer has space for (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html).

Try this one instead: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload2.html

You can give a callback to decide whether the read is complete and that could include waiting for and checking a length provided by another channel once the writer has written its message (if you've determined a deadlock-free way to do that) or just before the message proper.

Adding this completion condition makes it work:

```
[&](auto&& ec, auto&& bytes_read){
    return bytes_read < 5 ? 5 - bytes_read : 0;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @codeshot is correct, but it is one of several solutions - which is most appropriate is dependent entirely upon the protocol you're using across the TCP connection.

For example, in a traditional Key-Length-Value style protocol, you would do two reads:

1. Using `boost::asio::async_read` (or equivalent) to read into fixed length buffer to obtain the fixed-length header
2. Use the length specified by the header to create a buffer of the required size, and repeat step 1 using it

There's a good example of this in the [chat server example code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp).

If you were using HTTP or RTSP (the latter is what I was trying to do), then you don't know how much is data is coming, all you care about is receiving a packet's worth of data (I know this is an oversimplification due to the `Content-Length` header in responses, chunked transfer encoding, etc. but bear with me).  For this you need `async_read_some` (or equivalent), see the [HTTP server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/connection.cpp).